# Response.Clear in ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net

I have recently upgraded some of my web applications to ASP.NET 3.5 by installing the framework on the server and setting up my web applications acrodingly and all is well, however.

On some pages, I want to clear the current contents of the response buffer with code like this:

```
Response.Clear();
// Output some stuff
Response.End();
```

But this now isn't working in 3.5 when it did in 2.0. I have also tried setting the response buffer to false but this didn't work either.

Can anyone let me know why it isn't working or if there is a work around?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try setting Buffer="True" in the Page Directive of the page and not in codebehind.

I just tried this in VS2008 on a Web Site project:

1. Create new item
2. Choose "Web page"
3. Leave all the html-tags in there, just for fun
4. Fill the `page_load` like this

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
   {  
     Response.Write("test1");  
     Response.Clear();  
     Response.Write("test2");  
     Response.End();  
   }
   ```

It will then output "test2" without any html-tags.