# transform Dataset to XSLT

Tags: asp.net, xslt

I am new to xslt.I am trying to present the data of a dataset in aspx page using XSLT. I have tried like this...

I have a default.aspx page, test.xslt. I have a dataset which is having some data. I tried to transform as follows..

```cs
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XmlDataDocument dataDoc = new XmlDataDocument(DS);
XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load(xsltContactFile);
transform.Transform(dataDoc, null, sw);
```

where do i give the aspx page.

Please Could anyone help me to solve the above issue.

Thanks,
Bharath

Comment: This seems to be an ASP.NET question, not ASP classic

Comment: @Rico There was a 3p edit which added the erroneous asp classic tag.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've transformed to HTML, the quick and dirty way to output your transformed HTML would be to simply write the result directly to the response stream, e.g. in `Page_Load` of `default.aspx`

([Set Page Buffer = true first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154/response-clear-in-asp-net-3-5))

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
```

Slightly more elegant would be to paste the converted HTML into a control, e.g. using the InnerHtml of a div (runat=server) of on the page (after removing the root html and body tags from you XSL).

And more elegant still would be to write a HttpHandler.

However, if your XSLT transforms to XML not HTML then use the Xml control to control formatting of the XML on your page.

All of this is [discussed quite thoroughly here](https://www.xmlfiles.com/articles/transforming-xml-with-xslt-and-asp/).

One question though - the usual way to present a list of data (such as returned from a DataSet) in ASP.NET WebForms would be to use a GridView or Repeater control? You might find this easier to use than writing custom XSLT?